# What's the difference between filters with the same cutoff frequency, but different component values?

Tags: audio, filter

I've heard mention of this topic, and it seems pretty useful, as I'd like to design high-quality audio equipment & synthesizers. But I've never heard it explained, only mentioning that it "changes the sound".

Say I want a low pass filter with a cutoff of 1 kHz. There's a (theoretically infinite) number of component values I can choose. Two examples:

1. 15 Ω resistor, 10.61 µF capacitor.
2. 47 kΩ, 3.39 nF cap.

I heard it mentioned from an EE guru that this changes the sound of the filter. I even found the paper he mentioned of how it changes, but I couldn't make head or tails of it as it was heavily centered around math instead of sound. **I'll try to find it again so ya'll can take a look at it.**

If anyone can explain it — especially in terms of what value it would have for the sound of something — it would be fantastic.

Comment: How about a link to the paper, or at least the title and name of the author?

Comment: @JRE I'll try to find it. It's buried in a podcast somewhere...

Comment: Yes, different passives will result in different noise, THD, slew-rate etc.

Answer (score 4):

The original question misses two important points that affect the choice.
A passive R-C filter is usually situated between two active circuits - a driver, and a reciever. A driver practically has certain output impedance, and the receiving stage has finite input impedance as well. These two factors are missing from the question, and the result depends on the value of these impedances.

If you have an ideal driver with **zero output impedance**, and ideal receiver with **infinite input** impedance, then the choice doesn't matter, any pair of R-C will behave identically, and the "sound" will sound exactly the same assuming that R and C don't have significant voltage dependence. The only difference is that the first circuit will draw quite a bit of more power than the second one.

However, if your driver and receiver do have finite impedance as any real circuits do, these impedances effectively change the cut-off frequency, which does have an effect on how this entire circuit will sound.

For example, if you have a driver with output impedance of 50 Ohms and choose the circuit #1, this will **lower** the cut-off frequency of this filter by a factor of 4, because the filter RC will effectively have the R as 50+15 Ohms. Which might have a serious effect on sound.

If your input stage has, say, an impedance of 20 kOhms, and you select the circuit #2, the low-frequency gain will be 1/3 of the initial one, which again will sound differently.

In summary, values of a passive filter (its "characteristic impedances") should be selected in accord with impedances of the stages it is connected in between. Generally the input filter impedance should be much higher than the driver's impedance, and the input impedance of receiver stage should be much higher than the filter's output impedance, all impedances should be estimated at the cut-off frequency.

Alternatively, you can run simple SPICE simulations of the filter including correct models of outputs and inputs, and adjust passive RC values to get the best desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You are right in that there are an infinite number of combinations that will achieve the same cutoff frequency and response.

The "changes the sound" statement is a bit of a problem. It shouldn't unless there is some other characteristic of the components coming into play. This would typically be some inductance or resistance in certain types of capacitors that would cause some subtle changes in the response.

The choice of components will usually be a compromise and will include such considerations as:

- **Drive capability of the preceding stage.** Your 15 Ω resistor, for example, may overload the previous stage whereas choosing 1.5 MΩ might make it susceptible to noise.
- **Input impedance of the following stage.** If this is low it may force the designer to use lower values for the filter.
- **Size of capacitor.** Choosing high value capacitors may increase cost and board footprint or height whereas all the resistors are probably the same price.
- **Capacitor type.** Certain types are better suited to audio. (I'm out of touch with current trends in this area.)
- **Capacitor value.** Capacitors have a more limited number of discrete values than resistors. The designer will probably pick a standard capacitor and then calculate the resistor to suit.

As usual, the design will be a compromise with optimum performance somewhere between and well away from the extremes.

---

> If anyone can explain it — especially in terms of what value it would have for the sound of something ...

This text may help.

> In general, there are 3 types of capacitors that will be available in the values that are appropriate as AC coupling in most signal paths: electrolytic, tantalum and ceramic. Each has strengths and weaknesses.
>
> Electrolytic capacitors are generally the best performing for this purpose. They are very linear when biased by the Common Mode voltages present in most SigmaDSP audio paths and their low ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance) makes them attractive as an 'invisible' component when designing a circuit. They are fairly low cost as well. However, electrolytic capacitors have quite a large footprint and they will suffer from degradation of value and performance over time - especially in a high temperature environment. They literally 'dry out' and become a high pass filter in the signal path. High temperature versions are available and will hold up well over a long period of time.
>
> Tantalum capacitors are a reasonable alternative, however they are more expensive than electrolytics and are not available in as many values. As polarized capacitors, they must also be biased, however I have not found them to be as linear in an audio path as electrolytic capacitors. Some people say they "don't sound as good," however static single-tone distortion tests might not reveal any differences. On the positive side, tantalums do not dry out and so are appropriate for a long term high temperature environment. They are generally smaller than electrolytics for the same value.
>
> Both of the non-ceramic types will hold their capacitive value under use condition, unlike ceramics....
>
> Ceramic capacitors are generally not recommended for use as AC coupling in audio. They are attractive because of the size, cost and low ESR. However, when most ceramic capacitors are biased, the capacitive rating can decrease by as much as 50%! The higher grade (X7R) types suffer less from this, but you should be aware that a 1 uF might be acting like a 0.68uF in the circuit. We have also found that ceramic capacitors suffer from microphonic effects: the audio passing through the part will actually physically resonate and cause distortion! I would only use ceramic capacitors in the audio path where performance is not an issue, but size and cost are your higher priority. NP0 and C0G are the best of the ceramics, however I don't think you will find these types available in appropriate values.

Source: [Engineer Zone - Analog.com](https://ez.analog.com/thread/3465).

Comment: Note that your quoted stuff from AD is talking about **COUPLING** caps, which if appropriately sized have little AC voltage across them (That is rather the point), for parts in a **Filter** however, that assumption does not hold and the components of choice become C0G ceramics (where the value is low enough) or film parts.

Comment: Thanks, @DanMills. As mentioned, I haven't been keeping touch with this aspect of audio for some time.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between filters with the same cutoff frequency,
>   but different component values?

For a simple R-C filter with a low impedance driving signal and a high impedance receiving circuit there is no theoretical difference across a vast swathe of combinations of R and C.

However, your title could be taken to mean a slightly more complex circuit made from a resistor, capacitor and inductor. For this, the cut-off frequency is defined by: -

\$f = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$

And, there also exists an infinite number of L-C combinations that would fit the bill for a given cut-off frequency. However, for a given L-C combination, R can play a big part in shaping the filter response. We talk about Q factor and the higher the Q factor the peakier the response and this would make a great difference to the sound of an audio signal.

For a simple R-L-C low pass filter with R in series with L, Q factor is defined as this mathematically: -

[image]

[image]

So now, you should be able to see that Q factor is affected by the series resistor AND the ratio of L to C. In other words, for a given cut-off frequency AND a desired Q factor, there is a much more restricted number of values that would practically fit the bill.

So, you may be wondering what Q factor does and hopefully this picture will give you an answer: -

[image]

With a low value of Q you get a slow rolling-off attenuation of higher frequencies. As Q increases to around unity you get a flatter response at low frequencies and a more sudden change after the cut-off frequency has been reached. As Q increases more you get a development of a peak in the response and this will be quite noticable in audio applications and is used quite often in voltage controlled filters in synthesizers to give a rich sweeping effect with time.