# what is the importance of input and output impedance of a RL low pass filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, power-electronics, passive-filter

I read from the book that for a good voltage coupling, the input impedance must be larger than the output impedance of the previous stage, which requires a min value of Zin since the frequency of the input signal is not known. Also the output impedance must be smaller than the input impedance of the next stage, which requires a max value  of the output impedance.

My question is what is voltage coupling? is it like for eliminating the DC component of the input voltage?
and also also the output impedance must be below a max value to insure good voltage coupling?

[image]

Comment: You must avoid loading between stages. This can shift your corner frequency. To achieve this a voltage in voltage out device must have high input impedance and low output impedance.

Comment: Not sure what is "voltage coupling", but effect of impedance of input and outputs on charachteristics of filters was covered in many topics here, see examples https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/330856/117785 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/405464/117785

Answer (score 1):

I interpret "voltage coupling" to mean minimizing the voltage drop through the impedance of the source.  If the source has 10K output impedance, and your load (the filter plus any load after it) has 20 ohms input impedance, most of the voltage drop--and therefore the power--is consumed by the generator itself, with little being applied to the load.  Similarly, if the load impedance is much higher than the source impedance, nearly the full voltage generated by the source will be seen at the load.